# Restore traps without a temp file

Tags: bash, sh, bash-trap, shell-trap

Without arguments `trap` prints the currently set commands for all traps.  However, a subshell does not inherit traps, so the canonical example for saving and restoring traps fails in bash:

```
save_traps=$(trap)
...
eval "$save_traps"
```

The trap on the RHS of the assignment runs in a subshell, so save_traps is always the empty string.  Other than writing the output of `trap` to a temporary file, how can a script find the current command set for a trap?

Comment: In the main script, can you `export` the traps to the sub-shells?

Comment: For what it's worth, even using a temporary file, you can write it as a single command: `trap > trap.$$ && save_traps=$(< trap.$$) && rm trap.$$`. Not quite as terse as `save_traps=$(trap)`, but at least you won't have a temporary file floating around that *whole* time.

Comment: @ruakh The problem with the temporary file is that there is no way to ensure it is deleted.  Normally, you set a trap to remove the file before you create the file, but that cannot be done here since you lose the previous value of the trap.  Writing the command as a one-liner does not avoid the possibility of leaving the temporary file on the filesystem.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Well, but even setting a trap doesn't *ensure* that the file is deleted, because you can't *ensure* that the trap gets run, and even if it does, you can't *ensure* that it successfully deletes the file.

Comment: well, what is the probability that the temp file isn't deleted? And how important is that in your over all system? can't you just do a pre-sweep on trap-tmpfiles at beginning of script OR if your program never stops, have a crontab entry that finds trap-tmpFiles, waits one second, then deletes them? Not pretty, but I think you're up against the trade off of unix processes, and shells. Do you really want to be coding in Java (or other highly proscribed languages? ;-)? My projects usually have low-risk, so with low-probability cases, I let it go. Maybe zsh or rc has something 4 this? Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works for me.

Create a sample trap:

```
$ trap
$ trap echo SIGIO
$ trap
trap -- 'echo' SIGIO
```

Store the trap into `save_traps`:

```
$ save_traps=$(trap)
```

Remove:

```
$ trap SIGIO
$ trap | wc -l
   0
```

Restore:

```
$ eval "$save_traps"
$ trap
trap -- 'echo' SIGIO
```

Tested with:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: to save a specific signal, like INT for example, you can use "save_traps=$(trap -p INT)"

Answer (score 1):

Although the Bash manpage seems to say that traps are reset in subshells, and command substitution is executed in a subshell, running `trap` inside `$()` works anyway (tested in Bash 3.2 and 4.2). It is also mentioned in POSIX that `traps=$(trap)` should work.

Thanks to `pgas` in `#bash` at `irc.freenode.net`.

Comment: Indeed it does work in 3.2.25, and the failure that I was seeing was in 3.00.15.  That is an incredibly annoying bug.